# Fine tuning last x layers of BERT

Tags: tensorflow, module, google-colaboratory, embedding

I am trying to fine tune BERT just on specific last layers ( let's say 3 last layers). I want to use Google Colab for training on TPU. I am using [hub.Module](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/api_docs/python/hub/Module) to load BERT and fine tune it and then use the fine tuned output for my classification task.

`bert_module = hub.Module(BERT_MODEL_HUB, tags=tags, trainable=True)`

`hub.Module` has the option to set the model as trainable or non trainable, but nothing as partially trainable ( just specific layers)

Does anybody know how I can train just last 1,2, or 3 layers of BERT using `hub.Module`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can set it manually in the trainable variables list. The following is my implementation of Bert layer in tensorflow-keras-

```
class BertLayer(tf.layers.Layer):
 def __init__(
    self,
    n_fine_tune_layers=10,
    pooling="first",
    bert_path="https://tfhub.dev/google/bert_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1",
    **kwargs,
):
    self.n_fine_tune_layers = n_fine_tune_layers
    self.trainable = True
    self.output_size = 768
    self.pooling = pooling
    self.bert_path = bert_path
    if self.pooling not in ["first", "mean"]:
        raise NameError(
            f"Undefined pooling type (must be either first or mean, but is {self.pooling}"
        )

    super(BertLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

 def build(self, input_shape):
    self.bert = hub.Module(
        self.bert_path, trainable=self.trainable, name=f"{self.name}_module"
    )

    # Remove unused layers
    trainable_vars = self.bert.variables
    if self.pooling == "first":
        trainable_vars = [var for var in trainable_vars if not "/cls/" in var.name]
        trainable_layers = ["pooler/dense"]

    elif self.pooling == "mean":
        trainable_vars = [
            var
            for var in trainable_vars
            if not "/cls/" in var.name and not "/pooler/" in var.name
        ]
        trainable_layers = []
    else:
        raise NameError(
            f"Undefined pooling type (must be either first or mean, but is {self.pooling}"
        )

    # Select how many layers to fine tune
    for i in range(self.n_fine_tune_layers):
        trainable_layers.append(f"encoder/layer_{str(11 - i)}")

    # Update trainable vars to contain only the specified layers
    trainable_vars = [
        var
        for var in trainable_vars
        if any([l in var.name for l in trainable_layers])
    ]

    # Add to trainable weights
    for var in trainable_vars:
        self._trainable_weights.append(var)

    for var in self.bert.variables:
        if var not in self._trainable_weights:
            self._non_trainable_weights.append(var)

    super(BertLayer, self).build(input_shape)

  def call(self, inputs):
    inputs = [K.cast(x, dtype="int32") for x in inputs]
    input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids = inputs
    bert_inputs = dict(
        input_ids=input_ids, input_mask=input_mask, segment_ids=segment_ids
    )
    if self.pooling == "first":
        pooled = self.bert(inputs=bert_inputs, signature="tokens", as_dict=True)[
            "pooled_output"
        ]
    elif self.pooling == "mean":
        result = self.bert(inputs=bert_inputs, signature="tokens", as_dict=True)[
            "sequence_output"
        ]

        mul_mask = lambda x, m: x * tf.expand_dims(m, axis=-1)
        masked_reduce_mean = lambda x, m: tf.reduce_sum(mul_mask(x, m), axis=1) / (
                tf.reduce_sum(m, axis=1, keepdims=True) + 1e-10)
        input_mask = tf.cast(input_mask, tf.float32)
        pooled = masked_reduce_mean(result, input_mask)
    else:
        raise NameError(f"Undefined pooling type (must be either first or mean, but is {self.pooling}")

    return pooled

def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return (input_shape[0], self.output_size)
```

Focus on the following line in the above code-

```
trainable_layers.append(f"encoder/layer_{str(11 - i)}")
```

You can set the n_fine_tune_layers argument to be 1/2/3 by default or maybe pass it while declaring the layer -

```
def __init__(self, n_fine_tune_layers=2, **kwargs):
```

Comment: -1 this answer is incorrect. This simply makes the last N variables trainable, but 1) each BERT layer consists of more than one variable and 2) the layers are lexographically sorted. (Side note: please cite the source for the code)

Answer (score 1):

The below code is simply taken from this post (https://towardsdatascience.com/bert-in-keras-with-tensorflow-hub-76bcbc9417b) and is not correct.

```
trainable_vars = self.bert.variables

trainable_vars = trainable_vars[-self.n_fine_tune_layers:]
```

Will return the variables in alphabetical order, not in the actual layer order. 
As such, it will return Layer 11 before Layer 4 etc. This is not what you want.

I haven't worked out exactly how to get the actual order in which the layers are implemented but will update this answer when I do!

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: Nauman, I actually ended up using the original BERT code base and modifying from there - see my full implementation here https://github.com/BountyCountry/BERT-Multilabel-Classifier

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the code from the [blog post](https://towardsdatascience.com/bert-in-keras-with-tensorflow-hub-76bcbc9417b), we can select the correct layers. This is also resolved in the repo linked to the blog post, albeit in a less performant way.

[link to pull request](https://github.com/strongio/keras-bert/pull/9)

```
def build(self, input_shape):
    self.bert = hub.Module(
        bert_path,
        trainable=self.trainable,
        name="{}_module".format(self.name)
    )

    trainable_vars = self.bert.variables

    # Remove unused layers
    trainable_vars = [var for var in trainable_vars if not "/cls/" in var.name]

    # ===========Replace incorrect line with:====================
    # Select how many layers to fine tune. note: this is wrong in the original code
    import re
    def layer_number(var):
        '''Get which layer a variable is in'''
        m = re.search(r'/layer_(\d+)/', var.name)
        if m:
            return int(m.group(1))
        else:
            return None

    layer_numbers = list(map(layer_number, trainable_vars))
    n_layers = max(n for n in layer_numbers if n is not None) + 1 # layers are zero-indexed
    trainable_vars = [var for n, var in zip(layer_numbers, trainable_vars) 
                      if n is not None and n >= n_layers - self.n_fine_tune_layers]

    # ========== Until here ====================

    # Add to trainable weights
    self._trainable_weights.extend(trainable_vars)

    # Add non-trainable weights
    for var in self.bert.variables:
        if var not in self._trainable_weights:
            self._non_trainable_weights.append(var)

    super(BertLayer, self).build(input_shape)
```